# Can't start with google play services in android studio

Tags: android, google-play-services

It gives me an error in logcat. I think I missed something when I was adding library project...

```
/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

I'm following [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) instruction.

I've copied google play services library project to libs folder.

I've edited manifest. My build.gradle file

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

What else do I need?

EDIT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dictionaryimporter.app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dictionaryimporter.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.dictionaryimporter.app.WordsAddingService" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Google Play Services from the SDK Manager?
If you have, did you include it as a library (not adding a project reference, it is slightly different)

Here's an example

[Android - Google Maps api via Google Play Services](http://www.digitalopium.com/android-google-maps-api-tutorial/)

Comment: Yes, I've downloaded it.
How should I "include it as a library?"

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot that I'm working in android studio. So I need instructions on how to do that in AS not eclipse. I know how to do that in eclipse.

Comment: Try this for Android Studio:  File -> Project  Structure -> Modules

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your project name, then select Properties> Android> Add> select-google-play-services press OK.

After that add MAP Key in your manifest.

Here is a complete and very useful tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Follow the steps and you will not have any difficulties or errors.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#top
This page has all the details regarding Android Studio.

Comment: Guys... Really... I've read it about ten times already. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @user1685095 in your manifest you have to include "Google API Key"

Answer (score 0):

hi pls check your manifest file this should have this part as child of

```
    <application> 

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

...........

</application>
```

pls check site    http://instantiatorgratification.blogspot.in/2013/05/google-play-services-with-android-studio.html for clearance. it may have your answer.